# Meaning of asozial in German language

Tags: meaning, english-to-german

I recently heard the word "asozial" is an insult in Germany. As far as I know, in other cultures it is not perceived as an insult in general. How bad is it in meaning in German culture?

Comment: Example of a "false friend" - something that looks similar to a word in another language, but totally different meaning. Sensibel ≠ sensible. Pathetisch ≠ pathetic. And many others.

Comment: @gnasher729: prägnant ≠ pregnant, ich will ≠ I will, bekommen ≠ become

Comment: Note that being "asozial" was a crime in national socialism (and I think under socialist rule in the GDR), specifically the crime of rubbing national socialists somehow the wrong way. This was enough to get you murdered in a concentration camp. I know that some people use the word very casually (in the sense that they mean exactly the same thing as the Nazis, but would not go out of their way to have them murdered themselves), but I still would suggest you avoid the word.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast a German teacher I had at high school loved to tell the apocryphal story of a German tourist requesting to "become a shrimp" in a restaurant abroad...

Comment: preservative ≠ Präservativ :-)

Comment: Also a classic "I have a date with your chef!" (for a job interview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing to note is that the word *antisozial* may exist but is not very common; *asozial* covers its meanings as well. German equivalents to English *asocial* would be *ungesellig*, *einzelgängerisch* or *eigenbrötlerisch.*

With respect to use and history of the word the [Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asozialit%C3%A4t) is quite elaborate and, as far as I can tell, accurate.

The word *asozial* has been used under the Nazis and in the GDR to discriminate against and to justify persecution of certain groups of people who were non-conformant. The violated norms could be cultural (hippies, Sinti and Romanies), social (homeless), economic (no steady employment) or psychological (mentally ill). Often several of these deviations from the norm occur together: Most homeless will be unemployed, and mental illnesses among them are common. In most cases there are visual clues like shabby or non-standard clothes and lacking or non-standard haircuts which make a visual categorization easy.

In the way my grandmother and mother used the word, the reverberations of the Nazi use were clearly palpable; *asozial* was used as a term of abuse against people who were perceived as inferior or debased. A neighborhood with subsidized housing was where the *Asozialen* lived.

The subtext stemming from the Nazi worldview that was never consciously reflected — or maybe agreed with — was that being *asozial* was an intrinsic condition that was of course also passed on to the offspring. It is obvious that such a concept leads to specific policies of which putting people in concentration camps is only the most consequent one.

**To me the word *asozial* is quite toxic, in a line with the N-word or calling someone a spastic. I would strongly advise not to use it.**

Answer (score 21):

The German word *»asozial«* means in English

> anti social = against the needs and rights of the society

People who behave *asozial* violate basic rights of other people.

- A person who plays loud music in the middle of the night, so that other people can't sleep, acts *asozial.*
- A person who smokes cigars when they are in a closed room with little children acts *asozial.*

But some people use this word also for people who in fact just need help. They call homeless people or long-term unemployed person *asozial* (*»Assi«* = short for *»Asozialer«*) just because they receive financial support from the welfare system, although most of them do not really behave *asozial.*

Comment: asozial is often used like antisozial. when used in regard to homeless people, it retains it's original meaning: not part of normal society.

Comment: Worth noting: that's not what the actual English word "antisocial" typically means (though I do see it listed in the dictionary). In typical parlance, someone is "antisocial" if they don't want to be social, that is, to spend time with other people, especially if it defeats others' efforts to be social, such as by not participating in a group activity.

Comment: @Benjamin why is not being part of "normal" society considered as an insult? The definition of "normal" is a really relative concept. Why do Germans collectively think that everyone has to fit in? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @nmd_07: This has nothing to do with "Germans collectively". Looking down on people who are (perceived to be) different has happened in all societies in all ages since the beginning of humankind, and is even observed in animals. Nothing to do with Germans, Germany, or the German language. Not everybody goes to the extremes that my country went to to eradicate people who are (perceived to be) different, but it is by no means unique to Germany.

Comment: @nmd_07: IMHO drawing the line around "normal" gives a wrong impression of the meaning. There are plenty of types of people who are not a part of "normal" society, but by far not all of them are "asozial".

Comment: I tent to object: "asozial" is strongly negative. It does not mean the person is "not nice", but it means the person lives against what is considered social standards, like lying around drunken every day, smelling strongly due to not washing, using very bad language, etc.

Comment: @nmd_07 What one person finds asozial, the next person might find acceptable or maybe even perfectly normal. It is usually used as value judgement, and like all value judgements it is subjective. We germans agree what the word asozial means, we have different opinions on what constitutes asozial behaviour though.

Comment: Studying chemistry spoiled me: when I read *Assi*, I pronounce it with /s/ and understand *Assistent*. The short form of *Asozialer* would, to me, be *Asi* and pronounced with /z/. But I am not aware if my usage conforms to spelling norms (if such a norm exists for these abbreviations).

Comment: https://youtu.be/s0VTfB7nAH4?t=32

Comment: @Peeja Some people use the term "asocial" for someone who simply shuns social contact, and "anti-social" for someone who is a menace to others. Certainly terms like "anti-social behaviour" do not mean loners who spend all day in their rooms...

Comment: This answer is incomplete in a way that makes it wrong.

Answer (score 13):

The word is composed of two words: "sozial" has about the same meaning as "social" in English and comes from the latin "socius" (comrade, member). Words like "society" also come from "socius".

The prefix "a-" is greek and means "devoid of", "not concerned by", "not having...", etc.. This is a slight difference to "anti-" which means "contrary to". Someone "antisozial" is (actively) acting against societies norms - someone "asozial" is not concerned with societies norms at all.

In day-to-day German use of language the word "asozial" is usually meant as "not concerned with the well-being of ones surroundings", but - as @Hubert Schölnast" pointed out - often with the connotation of "not contributing to societies advancement" for whatever arbitrary reason. It also has the connotation of "inhumane", "inconsiderate", "ruthless", "reckless" or simply "unkind".

I hope this helps.

bakunin

Answer (score 3):

In a common way most young people use it, it has a meaning of a person who does not have a job and gets financial support from the system like Hubert said. But that is not the only thing. In addition it describes people also as persons that don't really take care of themselves, don't clean their rooms at home and in general do not do very much all the whole day although they have the time for it. You can also use it with an image of a person who consumes a lot of beer and other liquor.
I think it has a different meaning for each person who uses the word *asozial*, but this should cover the most common meanings.

Comment: So basically "asozial" means to be considered "not belonging to the society", but it's independent of racism.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the excellent answer by Hubert, asozial is generally quite derogatory and informal, and usually applied to young people; an English comparison that comes to mind is "Chav", or perhaps "Asbo".

Answer (score 0):

If I had to translate the common meaning of "asozial/assi" as an insult directly, I think "trashy" is a really good fit.